# STM32G4 Irq Handler block main function

Tags: c, stm32, bare-metal

I am trying to write a USART interrupt to read input from a serial terminal and pass that value to another function. While the interrupt works, it is for some reason blocking the program as if I were to go into debug mode, the program would keep looping at the USART2_IRQHandler().

```
void USART2_Init(void){
    RCC->APB1ENR1 |= RCC_APB1ENR1_USART2EN;
    RCC->AHB2ENR  |= RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOAEN;
    
    
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~(GPIO_MODER_MODE2|GPIO_MODER_MODE3|GPIO_MODER_MODE5);
    GPIOA->MODER |= (0x02 << GPIO_MODER_MODE2_Pos | 0x02 << GPIO_MODER_MODE3_Pos | 0x01 << GPIO_MODER_MODE5_Pos);
    GPIOA->AFR[0] |= (0x07<<GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL2_Pos | 0x07 <<GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL3_Pos);
    GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS5;
    
    USART2->CR1 |= USART_CR1_TXEIE;
    USART2->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RXNEIE;
    USART2->BRR  = (uint16_t)(16000000/9600);
    
    USART2->CR1 |= USART_CR1_TE;
    USART2->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RE;
    USART2->CR1 |= USART_CR1_UE;
    
    NVIC->IP[USART2_IRQn] |= (0X01<<4);
    NVIC->ISER[38>>5] |= (1<<(38%32));
}

void USART2_IRQHandler(void){
    if (USART2->ISR & USART_ISR_RXNE){
        rx = USART2->RDR;
        rx_counter++;
            
        if (rx_counter == 1){
            rx_buffer |= (rx & 0x0F) << 8;
            GPIOA->BRR |= GPIO_BRR_BR5;
        }
        else if (rx_counter == 2){
            rx_buffer |= rx & 0xFF;
            
            #ifdef AD5593R
            AD5593R_WriteDAC(AD5593R_CH1,rx_buffer);
            #endif
            
            #ifdef MCP4728
            MCP4728_GeneralCall(MCP4728_RESET);
            MCP4728_GeneralCall(MCP4728_WAKEUP);
            MCP4728_SingleTransmit(CHANNEL_A,rx_buffer);
            #endif
            
            rx_buffer = 0;
            rx_counter = 0;
            GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS5;
        }
        while((USART2->ISR & USART_ISR_RXNE)){}
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What do you think will happen when the RXNE flag happens to be set again before getting into `while((USART2->ISR & USART_ISR_RXNE)){}`?

Comment: No loops!!!!!!!!

Comment: KIIV has identified a race condition. You check for RXNE being set initially (Why would it _not_ be set if the ISR fires?). You clear RXNE when you fetch `USART2->RDR`. But, if usart gets another RX char before you leave, the loop that KIIV flagged will loop forever. You could get this if the ISR was delayed in processing the first char so that the 2nd char will appear quickly. Remove the [offending] `while` and change the top `if` to `while`

Comment: @th3virtuos0, A `while` loop such as `while((USART2->ISR & USART_ISR_RXNE)){` is scary code to have in an _interrupt handler_.  Consider  limiting loops  and not fully depend on expected hardware functionality.

Comment: @gulpr It's perfectly fine (and more efficient) to (as I mentioned) change the `if` to a `while` [I've done that many times] and can make all the difference if the ISR has been masked for an extended time (for whatever reason). The ISR prolog/epilog can be larger than the loop time, so the ISR should loop for very high baud rates. Otherwise, after you exit the ISR, you'll _immediately_ reenter the ISR (_with_ the extra overhead).

Comment: @CraigEstey it is not how this hardware should be used. If you have high baud rates - use DMA. Try 4 high speed UARTS + USB + 3x SPI + 2xI2C + USB + ETH  and you will see why it is wrong :)

Comment: With the "top" `while`, the ISR has only a single character buffer `rx_buffer`. This would need to become a queue. And, if the `MCP4728` et. al. calls are heavyweight, I might move them to task level. Or, if they _are_ heavyweight, all the more reason to loop.

Comment: @gulpr Possibly. _If_ we can get a trigger from the DMA to trigger on every 3rd char. Because we need to hit the DAC on every 3rd char. So, could we tolerate greater _latency_ from the DMA solution to gain throughput efficiency? And, how do we mimic the timing of the current setup? That is, the incoming RX data dictates the output frequency of the values we send to the DAC. So, we'd need to know more about what can be tolerated. This looks like a robotic PWM motor control I've seen with the remote processor doing the calculations and the STM32 doing the actual output to the H/W.

Comment: I'd consider not using interrupts until you know what you're doing. This ISR does far too much. A typical ISR would set a flag, give a semaphore, or send a message. Then some non-ISR code would take some action as appropriate.